# $L^2$ functions with compactly supported Fourier transforms form a Hilbert space

Tags: real-analysis, fourier-analysis, hilbert-spaces, lp-spaces, fourier-transform

Given a fixed compact subset of $\mathbb{R}$,  I want to show that square integrable functions on the real line whose fourier transforms are supported in the given compact set form a Hilbert space in the $L^2$ inner product. It was easy to show that the functions form a subspace. However I am stuck at the closedness of the subspace. Could anyone please help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$f_n \to f$ in $L^{2}$ implies $\hat {f_n} \to \hat {f}$ in $L^{2}$ and this implies that some subequence of $(\hat {f_n})$ converges almost everywhere to $\hat {f}$. Hence $\hat {f}$ is also supported by the compact set.

Comment: How can one show that the L^2 convergence of the original series implies the L^2 convergence of the fourier transform? I think I saw some similar contents in the past but my memories are faded away now. Could you please explain?

Comment: The map which takes a a function $f \in L^{2}$ to its Fourier transform is an isometry. The very construction of FT for $L^{2}$ goes through this isometry property.

Comment: Oh is this construction called the Plancherel theorem according to Folland Real Analysis?

Comment: Yes, it is called the Plancherel Theorem.